# TypeORM - Query DB With Array Param - Postgres?

Tags: graphql, typeorm

I have no problem querying the technologies field with a single integer.  I have it setup as an array and can do full CRUD with it.

Queries with an array fail.  I've tried many more WHERE statements but nothing works.  From the docs this should work.  What to do please?

```
const techArray = [1, 6];
// const testArray = '{1, 6}';  // error: value.map is not a function
// A Postgres array must be in {}. But this fails with the above error.

return await getRepository(Projects)
   .createQueryBuilder("projects") // Create SQL alias.
   .where("projects.technologies = ANY ( :...id )", { id: techArray })
   // .where(':id = ANY (projects.technologies)', { id: techArray})
   .getMany();
```

The message I get in GraphQL Playlist:

```
"syntax error at or near ,"
```

Relevant entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Projects {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  project_id: number;
  ...
  @Column('int', { array: true, nullable: true })
  technologies: number;
  ...
```

Comment: Can you share Projects and Technologies entitiy definitions?

Comment: zenbeni, I could but they are just clutter.  As I mentioned everything works for CRUD and that includes INT[] columns.  Arrays go in and out just fine, and I can query for one id and get the correct results.  The issue is narrow, just query with an array param.  I'm trying to make a raw sql query work now.

Comment: Just added the relevant parts of the Projects entity.

Comment: I've opened this issue on TypeORM Github:  https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5201

Answer (score 0):

I consider this solution to be a hack.  Since TypeORM will only work with an array of one integer element then I did a for loop with a for loop in it.  I get the results I want but it seems like way too much code.

```
public async findById(techArray) {

    let i;
    let items = [];

    for ( i = 0; i < techArray.length; i++ ) {

      let item = [];  // 0 out the array each iteration.

      item.push(techArray[i]);

      let objectArray = await this.entityManager
      .createQueryBuilder(Projects, "projects")
      // This works with [1]
      .where(":...ids = ANY (projects.technologies)", {ids: item})  
      .getMany();

      for ( let j = 0; j < objectArray.length; j++ ) {

        let objects = objectArray[j];
        console.log('objects in service: ', objects);

        items.push(objects);
      }

    }
    console.log('items in service: ', items);
    // This result is used by an Angular component for more processing.
    return await items; 
  }
```